# API Gateway integration with S3 where binary media types are not known in advance produces corrupt files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-api-gateway

I am creating an API Gateway with various endpoints, one of which gets objects that are binary files from S3 with everything defined in Terraform. It works fine if I set the gateway up with a predefined list of MIME types, eg:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "my_api" {
...
    binary_media_types = [ "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", 
       "application/msword",
       "application/pdf" ]
...
}
```

The problem is that I don't know ahead of time all of the MIME types that will exist in the bucket. If I try to use a generic binary MIME type like `application/octet-stream` I get additional characters in the response body and the file can't be opened. I've tried with a MIME type of `application/*` but I get an internal server error (presumably it can't be mapped).

The integration response settings have content handling set to passthrough with no header mappings or mapping templates. The method response also has just a 200 response with no header or model settings.

I've seen a few questions that talk about incorrect encoding between Lambda's Base64 string output and API Gateway but my scenario is just S3 -> API Gateway. I've looked at the below links but they don't seem to help me because they use predefined binary types:

[Integrating API Gateway with AWS Services S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html)

[API Gateway Content Encodings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-content-encodings-examples-image-s3.html)

[API Gateway Payload Encodings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings.html)

Is there a way of allowing wildcard binary types in API Gateway, and then passing through the integration Content-Type to the output? Alternatively, is there a way to use a generic MIME type such as `application/octet-stream` and stop API Gateway from adding additional characters?

Comment: Have you tried using `*/*`?

Comment: @Marcin you mean as a binary media type? When I try that I get internal server error and the API Gateway logs have `Unable to transform request`

Answer (score 0):

Please find below an example how to serve static content like images, PDF, etc. from an S3 bucket using api gateway.

Steps to reproduce:

- setup YOUR_BUCKET
- place a test image `test.png` into `s3://YOUR_BUCKET/test/test.png`
- set up a role `role/apigAwsProxyRole` which is allowed to read from `YOUR_BUCKET`
- create a new api in api gateway
- import the below OpenApi definition and overwrite your existing api
- In api gateway click on `Settings` on the left menu. Make sure that after the import you still have `*/*` in the binary content type.
- deploy the api, e.g. with stage `dev`
- access your static file: `https://0omkxxxxkj.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/v1/files/test/test.png`

Notice that the same setup also works with a private api endpoint. That way you can serve static content from S3 by making it only available through a private endpoint within your VPC.

```
{
  "swagger" : "2.0",
  "info" : {
    "version" : "1.0",
    "title" : "s3-static"
  },
  "host" : "0omkxxxxkj.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
  "basePath" : "/dev",
  "schemes" : [ "https" ],
  "paths" : {
    "/v1/files/{proxy+}" : {
      "get" : {
        "produces" : [ "application/octet", "application/json" ],
        "parameters" : [ {
          "name" : "proxy",
          "in" : "path",
          "required" : true,
          "type" : "string"
        } ],
        "responses" : {
          "200" : {
            "description" : "200 response",
            "schema" : {
              "$ref" : "#/definitions/Empty"
            },
            "headers" : {
              "Content-Type" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "500" : {
            "description" : "500 response"
          }
        },
        "x-amazon-apigateway-integration" : {
          "credentials" : "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/apigAwsProxyRole",
          "httpMethod" : "GET",
          "uri" : "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:s3:path/YOUR_BUCKET/{proxy}",
          "responses" : {
            "2\\d{2}" : {
              "statusCode" : "200",
              "responseParameters" : {
                "method.response.header.Content-Type" : "integration.response.header.Content-Type"
              }
            }
          },
          "requestParameters" : {
            "integration.request.path.proxy" : "method.request.path.proxy"
          },
          "passthroughBehavior" : "when_no_match",
          "type" : "aws"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions" : {
    "Empty" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "title" : "Empty Schema"
    }
  },
  "x-amazon-apigateway-binary-media-types" : [ "*/*" ]
}
```